# print the date of a mail.log line

Tags: sed, logs, date, output

I have a mail.log line and using sed and pipes I can extract the subject, the sender, and the recipient of the mail,

```
echo "Jul 15 09:04:38 mail postfix/cleanup[36034]: 4A4E5600A5DE0: info: header Subject: The tittle of the message from localhost[127.0.0.1]; from=<sender01@mydomain> to=<recipient01@mydomain> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.mydomain>" | sed -e 's/^.*Subject: //' -e 's/\]//' -e 's/from localhost//' -e 's/^.\];//' |sed -e 's/\[127.0.0.1; //' -e 's/proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.mydomain>//'
```

I have the output

```
The tittle of the message from=<sender01@mydomain> to=<recipient01@mydomain>
```

my desired output is

```
Jul 15 09:04:38 The tittle of the message from=<sender01@mydomain> to=<recipient01@mydomain>
```

How to extract the date and added it to the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly but put this at the beginning of the `sed` statement:

```
 -e 's/^\([[:alpha:]]+ [[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]+:[[:digit:]]+:[[:digit:]]+\).*Subject:\(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

Or if you always know that ' mail postfix' will be in the text at that position you can just use:

```
 -e 's/^\(.*\) mail postfix.*Subject:\(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

And other variations are possible. The key is to capture the date, skip over parts you don't care about, and again capture the remainder that you still need to process. To capture surround with `\(` and `\)` and to print what you've captured use `\n` where n is the position of a particular capture (first is 1, second is 2, etc.)

And now that you know this you can probably figure out how to eliminate all of the separate directives (-e), use multiple capture groups, and get it down to a single `sed` expression.